# Different integers derived from the same Python byte string

Tags: python, binary, python-2.7, hex, arrays

```
>>> import binascii, struct
>>> foo_hex = 'b1e92555'
>>> foo_bin = binascii.unhexlify(foo_hex)
>>> int(foo_hex, 16)
2984846677
>>> struct.unpack('i', foo_bin)[0]
1428548017
```

Why are these integers different? Which method is correct and how can the other one be changed to be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct` is interpreting the value using little-endian notation, while using `unhexlify` and `int(.., 16)` interprets it as a big-endian unsigned integer.

Use `<` or `>` to specify the endianness of your input, and use `I` to interpret it as a signed int:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>I', foo_bin)[0]
2984846677
>>> struct.unpack('<I', foo_bin)[0]
1428548017
```

See the [Byte Order, Size and Alignment section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) of the `struct` documentation page.